# VLC Media Player not installing in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vlc

I tried installing vlc media player by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

The terminal window showed the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the 
unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not installable
      Depends: libtar0 but it is not installable
      Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not installable
      Depends: libva1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not installable
      Depends: libvlccore7 (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Answer (score 1):

These commands might help you:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

What I am suggesting might be risky. So please proceed with caution:

`sudo aptitude install vlc -f`

`sudo aptitude install -f`

These commands solve the dependencies automatically and also give you some options so if you don't like one just say no and it'll show you another.

BUT IT MIGHT ALSO RESULT IN SOMETHINGS NOT WORKING AFTERWARDS.

Comment: alternatively you may try to fix broken packages using synaptic package manager

Answer (score 0):

Please try the Ubuntu software center. It's much easier to install apps.
Press the Super Key/windows key this will bring the Dash up, write Ubuntu Software Center. Open the Software Center and then search for VLC on the Software Center.

Comment: You can Download most needed software fro the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Initially, I tried that. It said dependencies not satisfiable.

Comment: I know there is a different way to install packages using the synaptic package manager which you can find on the Software Center. or you can download a .dev file which will install when you click on it similarly to a .exe on windows.

Comment: If that doesn't help.I don't know what is your problem sorry

Comment: make sure your system is updated

Answer (score 0):

Did a System-Upgrade disable the vlc - ppa or repository due to the upgrade? Then you'd only need to manually turn the ppa on again. I'd update the software list and reinstall all vlc stuff already installed. If not already done sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.